# FPDF - how to make getstringwidth globaly?

Tags: php, html, mysql, width, fpdf

I want to call `getstringwidth` already declared in another `while` when using `while` just for set width on next row.

My table heading :

```
while ($row2x = $stmt2x->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $string = $row2x['nama_kriteria'];
    $cellwidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($string);
    $pdf->Cell($cellwidth + 2,7,$row2x['nama_kriteria'],1,0,'L');
}
```

how can I use table heading width for my next table row?

My table row :

```
while ($rowrx = $stmtrx->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $pdf->Cell(/*$cellwidth + 2*/,7,$rowrx['nilai_rangking'],1,0,'L');
    }
```

for now, my table looks like:
[image: this]

any idea how to make it good-looking?

Comment: any idea please?

Comment: What happens if you put in "$cellwidth + 2,7"?

Comment: @Bernhard the table is null, because `$cellwidth` in my table heading is `while ($row2x = $stmt2x->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $string = $row2x['nama_kriteria'];
    $cellwidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($string);}` cellwidth i used on table row from table heading

Comment: need help please

Comment: not yet find out how to fix, any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to store width in array.

```
$width = array();
while ($row2x = $stmt2x->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $string = $row2x['nama_kriteria'];
    $cellwidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($string);
    $pdf->Cell($cellwidth + 2,7,$row2x['nama_kriteria'],1,0,'L');
    $width[] = $cellwidth + 2;
}

$i = 0;
while ($rowrx = $stmtrx->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $pdf->Cell($width[$i],7,$rowrx['nilai_rangking'],1,0,'L');
    $i++;
}
```

you need to fill the width array you get from the `$cellwidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($string);` then you just use the value from that width from width variable